# правильное подключение less

Tags: css, less

В первый раз решил попробовать поработать с препроцессором LESS. В некоторых источниках указано что нужно подключить .less, потом less.js и .css. В других подключен только .css который был скомпилирован LESS-ом. Визуально разницы никакой, но все же как будет правильнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

смотрите на своей мошите я подключаю

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

А на сервер  для лучшей сео оптимизации я компилирую в css и подключаю как css по рекомендации W3C. Да и ещё если вы не используете файлы просто так без виртуального сервера на своей машите то открывайте через mozila, потому как через chronium браузеры js просто так не запустится

Comment: да, я уже столкнулся с этой проблемой. А если просто подключить css скомпилированный и вообще не подключать less это будет ошибкой?

Comment: Нет просто пока вы не закончите работать это будет напрягать так постоянно делать. Поэтому пока работаю не компилирую, заканчиваю верстать  компилирую.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше, чтобы ваша среда разработки принимала от вас less, а при сохранении сохраняла три файла: оригинальный less, скомпиленные css (минифицированный) и map файлы

А подключать, конечно, лучше css, к чему браузеру лишний раз напрягаться на такую еруну, как трансформация less => css )

Если юзаете VS, то вот расширение [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/less)